# How to run the WLST script from Shell?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I am running python scripts from the shell script. And after executing the python script, CLASSPATH is being displayed.

Is there any way where I could eliminate the CLASSPATH and execute the `wlst`.

Thanks,
TJ

Answer (score 0):

Your question not that clear, though $CLASSPATH can set to blank with in shell script look like this.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CLASSPATH="" # this is only required for those who don't want CLASSPATH
# Here python script called
$MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh wlstscript.py
```

This may be helpful for others who are trying to call the wlst-script from shell